# How do I conditionally display text in an ASP TemplateView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a few fields that look like this in a website that uses ASP and VB (the data is displayed in a gridview):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Comp" SortExpression="NAM_CMPT" ItemStyle-Width="50%" ItemStyle-Wrap ="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="left">
     <ItemTemplate>                                                                     
         <asp:Label ID ="Label_Comp" runat="server"                            
              Text='<%# Eval("CDE_CMPT") + " - " + Eval("NAM_CMPT")%>' /> 
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And what I'm trying to do is display nothing in the field if the data is empty, and display the string you see in the Text property if there is data. Currently it displays the hyphen used in the Text string when there is no data. I tried several methods of formatting the Eval that I found online but was unable to find a working solution. I also tried using the

```
EmptyDataText
```

property however this seemed to have no effect.

I am new to ASP so that could be user error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use RowDataBound method for checking value of both fields

Comment: please add your `RowDataBound` event code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use eval for visible and check for data

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Comp" SortExpression="NAM_CMPT" ItemStyle-Width="50%" ItemStyle-Wrap ="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="left">
     <ItemTemplate>                                                                     
         <asp:Label ID ="Label_Comp" runat="server" visible='<%# If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("CDE_CMPT")), false, true)'                            
              Text='<%# Eval("CDE_CMPT") + " - " + Eval("NAM_CMPT")%>' /> 
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I haven't used VB.net is a while, so the syntax might be off.

Comment: I think you have to check both the string for making it visible or not